# Canonical Powershell Parameter Splatting for Unlike Cmdlets

Tags: powershell

Is there a proper way to use the *same* `$parameters` variable in both the `Get-ADUser` *and* the `Select` statements in the code below?

`Get-ADUser` has a parameter named "Properties" while `Select` has a parameter named "Property".

I do not want to manage multiple copies of a `$parameters` variable.

Any suggestions welcome.

```
import-module ActiveDirectory

$user = "SomeUserName"

$parameters = @{
    "Properties" = @(
        "msExchWhenMailboxCreated",
        "whenCreated"
     )
}

function get-ExchangeUserData {

    foreach ($user in $users){

        # Select @parameters does not work with Select.
        get-aduser $user @parameters | select @parameters

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this but they all could have arguments against your goal here.

## Use Parameter shortening to your advantage

```
$parameters = @{"Propert" = @("msExchWhenMailboxCreated", "whenCreated")}

# Select @parameters does not work with Select.
get-aduser user @parameters | select @parameters
```

We set the key in the hashtable to "propert" which is unambiguous in both   `Get-ADUser` and `Select-Object`. So you are still splatting both cmdlets with the exact same information. You could also use Prop which looks more pleasing and it conveys the same meaning.

## Watch for parameter aliases that work in your favour

While that previous solution is cool and all it is really not necessary in *this case* since [`Get-Aduser` supports 'property' as an alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps#optional-parameters). `$parameters = @{"Property" = @("msExchWhenMailboxCreated", "whenCreated")}` would work just fine.

## Break out the properties into another variable or call it separately

Not really splatting but it keeps with the logic of maintaining one list since you said

> I do not want to manage multiple copies of a `$parameters` variable.

```
$props = "msExchWhenMailboxCreated", "whenCreated"

$parameters = @{"Properties" = @($props)}

get-aduser user @parameters | select $props
```

or

```
$parameters = @{"Properties" = @("msExchWhenMailboxCreated", "whenCreated")}

# Select @parameters does not work with Select.
get-aduser user @parameters | select $parameters.Properties
```

Comment: I like all of these. Parameter shortening ... lol I didn't even think about this even though I do it all the time. Thank you! *Note: I think your second method has higher legibility, and probably what I would do in powershell code I expect other people to maintain*.

Comment: Agreed. I do like the first one but would only do it with proper comments. I would op for the second ones most of the time as they make more sense all around.

Comment: parameter shortening has a different name that escapes me now as well.

Comment: `@($props)` this syntax is unnecessary.  `$props` is already an array by virtue of the array comma operator.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I agree that it is redundant. However I am sure someone somewhere with someversion might have an issue with a scalar that should be an array.

Comment: `'one', 'two'` is `@('one', 'two')`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Indeed. What I was trying to say is that `'one'` is not `@('one')` and that historically caused issues for some people and there is a lot of v2 still out there.